# Simplify matrix into an upper triangular matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a tridiagonal matrix that I am trying to simplify into an upper triangular matrix using Mathematica, so I can use back substitution and solve my linear system. I have found the command `RowReduce`, but that simplifies the matrix too far, and I get an identity matrix, since the matrix I am trying to simplify is a square matrix. Is there a way in Mathematica to simplify a matrix into an upper triangular matrix?

Note: I want to solve the linear system by hand. I just want Mathematica to simplify the matrix.

Update: Specifically, I'd like to get an upper triangular matrix by using [Gaussian elimination](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html).

Comment: Check `UpperTriangularize`?

Comment: That just sets all the elements below the diagonal to 0. I actually want the first steps of Gaussian elimination to be applied.

Comment: [LUDecomposition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LUDecomposition.html)?

Comment: LU decomposition is a bit different than what I am hoping for. I would like to get an upper triangular matrix using Gaussian elimination (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html).

Comment: Look at `RowReduce`...

Comment: I mention in my original statement that I use RowReduce. What I want is to use RowReduce or something equivalent to that to get my matrix just to be upper triangular but not in reduced row echelon form.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: `QRDecomposition[m]` yields the QR decomposition for a numerical matrix `m`. The result is a list `{q,r}`, where `q` is an orthogonal matrix and `r` is an upper-triangular matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll illustrate on a smallish matrix, using exact arithmetic. That should make it relatively easy to verify correctness.

First we create a tridiagonal 5×5 matrix.

```
n = 5;
SeedRandom[33333];
mat = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {n, n}];
Do[mat[[i, j]] = 0; mat[[j, i]] = 0, {i, 3, n}, {j, 1, i - 2}];

mat

(*Out[68]= {{-30, -98, 0, 0, 0}, {12, 72, 29, 0, 0}, {0, -9, -49, 63, 
  0}, {0, 0, -21, 88, -16}, {0, 0, 0, -16, -98}} *)
```

To make it upper triangular we simply clear below pivots. I'm sure this can be done more slickly with `Fold`, but I'm more used to procedural methods for this sort of thing.

```
Do[mat[[i]] -= mat[[i, i - 1]]/mat[[i - 1, i - 1]]*mat[[i - 1]], {i, 2, n}]

mat

(* Out[70]= {
{-30, -98, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 164/5, 29, 0, 0},
{0, 0, -(6731/164), 63, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 375356/6731, -16},
{0, 0, 0, 0, -(9627006/93839)}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not always advised to perform LU decomposition without pivoting, for tridiagonal matrices or otherwise. Nevertheless, whenever it is stable (e.g. diagonally dominant cases), there is a simple formula for the $\mathbf L$ and $\mathbf U$ factors, based on the usual three-term recurrence for the determinant of a tridiagonal matrix (see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant)).

In particular, consider the tridiagonal matrix

```
MatrixForm[trid = With[{n = 5},
                       SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> Array[l, n - 1],
                                    Band[{1, 1}] -> Array[d, n],
                                    Band[{1, 2}] -> Array[u, n - 1]}, {n, n}]]]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 d[1] & u[1] & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 l[1] & d[2] & u[2] & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & l[2] & d[3] & u[3] & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & l[3] & d[4] & u[4] \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & l[4] & d[5] \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

We can use `RecurrenceTable[]` to evaluate the three-term recurrence for the tridiagonal determinant:

```
With[{n = 5},
     rr = RecurrenceTable[{y[n] == d[n] y[n - 1] - l[n - 1] u[n - 1] y[n - 2],
                           y[-1] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y[n], {n, 0, n}]];
```

Check:

```
Last[rr] == Det[trid] // Simplify
   True
```

Here, however, we are interested in using `rr` to build the desired decomposition. In particular, the required factors are:

```
With[{n = 5},
     lf = SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> Array[l, n - 1]/Ratios[Most[rr]],
                       Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, {n, n}];
     uf = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Ratios[rr], 
                       Band[{1, 2}] -> Array[u, n - 1]}, {n, n}];]
```

Check:

```
lf.uf == trid // Simplify
   True
```

---

Let's apply this to Daniel's example:

```
la = {12, -9, -21, -16};
da = {-30, 72, -49, 88, -98};
ua = {-98, 29, 63, -16};
```

`RecurrenceTable[]` does not play well when the diagonals are specified as lists, so I will demonstrate a technique for evaluating the three-term recurrence, based on repeated multiplication of $2\times 2$ matrices:

```
n = Length[da];
rr = FoldList[Dot, IdentityMatrix[2], 
              Transpose[{{ConstantArray[0, n], ConstantArray[1, n]},
                         {-Append[la ua, 0], da}}, {2, 3, 1}]][[All, 2, 2]]
   {1, -30, -984, 40386, 2252136, -231048144}
```

(I have previously used this in [this blog post](https://tpfto.wordpress.com/2019/04/26/on-inverting-a-tridiagonal-matrix/).)

The required factors are then

```
MatrixForm[lf = SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> la/Ratios[Most[rr]],
                             Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, {n, n}]]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{2}{5} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -\frac{45}{164} & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{3444}{6731} & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{26924}{93839} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

```
MatrixForm[uf = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Ratios[rr], 
                             Band[{1, 2}] -> ua}, {n, n}]]
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 -30 & -98 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{164}{5} & 29 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{6731}{164} & 63 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{375356}{6731} & -16 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{9627006}{93839} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that `uf` is the matrix Daniel obtained in his answer.

A final check:

```
lf.uf == SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> la, Band[{1, 1}] -> da,
                      Band[{1, 2}] -> ua}, {n, n}] // Simplify
   True
```